# Managing Virtualbox on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, rdp

We have some Windows product testers that need versions of Windows to test on. I was wondering if there's a way to install Ubuntu Server, and then virtualbox, and then host these sessions over the RDP protocol simultaneously so that we could have like Tester A on Windows XP while at the same time have Tester B on Windows 8?

Can we also have an easy interface to reboot virtualbox instances if they jam up or suddenly shut down, without having to reboot the entire server?

Answer (score 0):

The linux terminal server product ThinLinc version 4.0 do have support hosting VirtualBox VDI machines. It does support both persistent and shared VDI machines. The product is commercial but it is free to use up to 10 concurrent users.

For more information about VDI infrastrcture:

http://www.cendio.com/resources/docs/tag/pt04.html